# Java LockSupport Memory Consistency

Tags: java, api, concurrency, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

Java 6 API question. Does calling `LockSupport.unpark(thread)` have a *happens-before* relationship to the return from `LockSupport.park` in the just-unparked thread? I strongly suspect the answer is yes, but the Javadoc doesn't seem to mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked though the JDK code and it looks like LockSupport methods are normally called outside of synchronization blocks. So, your assumption seems to be correct.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old answer, but since the question is about the Java *API* and not the *implementation* provided by Sun/Oracle, looking at how the JDK uses `LockSupport` is not 100% correct. The JDK developers may make assumptions about their own implementation, while a portable application should not. In addition, there are ways to achieve a *happens-before* relationship that do not involve any `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: "... looked through the JDK code": Can you pls kindly post an hg URL for OpenJDK?

Answer (score 7):

I have just found this question because I was asking myself the same thing. According to [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/a_race_in_locksupport_park) by Oracle researcher [David Dice](https://labs.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=labs%3abio:0:29), the answer seems to be **no**. Here's the relevant part of the article:

> If a thread is blocked in `park()` we're guaranteed that a subsequent
>   `unpark()` will make it ready. A perfectly legal but low-quality
>   implementation of `park()` and `unpark()` would be empty methods, in which
>   the program degenerates to simple spinning. **An in fact that's the
>   litmus test for correct `park()`-`unpark()` usage.**

Empty `park()` and `unpark()` methods do not give you any *happens-before* relationship guarantees, so for your program to be 100% portable, you should not rely on them.

Then again, the [Javadoc of LockSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) says:

> These methods are designed to be used as tools for creating
>   higher-level synchronization utilities, and are not in themselves
>   useful for most concurrency control applications. The `park` method is
>   designed for use only in constructions of the form:
>
> `while (!canProceed()) { ... LockSupport.park(this); }`

Since you have to explicitly check some condition anyway, which will either involve `volatile` or properly synchronized variables, the weak guarantees of `park()` should not actually be problem, right?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can't now remember why I wanted to know this. I suspect I was wondering if when the running thread updated the condition and called `unpark`, if that would by itself guarantee the unparked thread would see the updated condition in a consistent state. It seems there is no guarantee, so the only safe choice is to explicitly arrange a memory barrier for the condition update.

Comment: I see. If there were a *happens-before* relationship between `park()` and `unpark()`, then the condition would not need to involve a memory barrier. So the question is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

If it isn't documented as such then you CANNOT rely on it creating a happens before relationship.

Specifically LockSupport.java in Hotspot code simply calls Unsafe.park and .unpark!

The *happens-before* relationship will generally come from a write-read pair on a volatile status flag or something similar.

Remember, if it isn't documented as creating a *happens-before* relationship then you **must** treat it as though it does not even if you can prove that it does on your specific system. Future systems and implementations may not. They left themselves that freedom for good reason.